# Using data-provider and parallel in Testng, how to run before method, after method and test in same thread for a given test.?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am running my test suite through testNG xml. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
  <test name="Test" group-by-instances="true" parallel="instances">
    <classes>
      <class name="packageName"></class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I am using the data-provider with annotation parallel=true. I have like 2000 test cases which runs in a loop through one test case with different data. The test runs well when its not parallel.
When i try to run the test in parallel, in 4 threads, the before and after method gets executed in the same thread, however my test method is allocated altogether different thread. 
How do i make sure that for a test case, before method , after method and test all run in the same thread for a test instance.

Comment: See [Reporter.java:28-31](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/336f0ef401e9f564b8dc99d601ac80e8891ac2c1/src/main/org/testng/Reporter.java#L28-L31). The `BeforeTest`, `Test`, and `AfterTest` methods always run in the same thread. You can test this by using [`Thread.currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--). See [gist](https://gist.github.com/mfulton26/adf8d3f9b966e103cb91).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried singleThreaded? like below example

```
@Test(singleThreaded = true)

 public class DemoForMethodOrdering {

  ///implementation here
}
```

please find information about singleThreaded in testng doc [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Yes, my code works fine for singleThreaded=true. Problem comes with  Multithreading.

Comment: Hi, yes in Multithreading only if we specify singleThreaded=true all methods in that class will be executed by same thread. thats what you are looking for right?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. However my requirement is to open 7 browsers, and each browser should run in independent thread , so before, after and test for a test case in that browser happen in same thread.